# Lossless jpeg compression in opencv

Tags: opencv, jpeg

Is it possible to achieve lossless compression in opencv without using an API such as libjpeg? I want to modify the DCT coefficients and get the same values when reading the image again.

I've tried to implement it like this : 8x8 RGB pixel blocks -> YCrCb -> DCT -> Quantization -> modify some coefficient values -> deQuantization -> IDCT -> RGB -> save the image. The lossy part, I've noticed, is when I apply the inverse DCT and save.

Comment: The step where you modify the coefficients is the part where you introduce loss, Using DCT is not lossless compression. Do you save the image using cv2.imwrite().  cv2.imwrite has one argument  CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY. You can set this value from 0-100, with 100 being the best. I am not sure, but maybe its lossless.

Comment: Why not simply use PNG if you want lossless? Or TIFF with LZW or BZ4 compression?

Comment: I want to implement Jsteg which hides data inside dct coefficients and is designed for jpeg. Upon extraction I want to get that data back but I seem to lose a lot of it due to the lossy compression. I already set the jpeg quality to 100 but that's not my main problem. Even if I return the mat object and apply the same steps on it , I'm still not able to obtain the original embedded data.